# Go: How to parse only date to time.Time?

Tags: go

I want to parse only date value to `time.Time`.
For example I have date in this format: `2016-03-31`, and I want to parse it, like: `time.Parse(FORMAT, "2016-03-31")`.

But it always fail.

What is the correct format string to use to parse only date with this format?

I have the code below as example, it is on playground also: https://play.golang.org/p/0MNLr9emZd

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var dateToParse = "2016-03-31"

func main() {
    format := "2006-12-01"
    parseDate(format)
}

func parseDate(format string) {
    t, err := time.Parse(format, dateToParse)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Format:", format)
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println("")
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Works Format:", format)
    fmt.Println(t)
    fmt.Println("")
}
```

The output is this:

```
Format: 2006-12-01
parsing time "2016-03-31" as "2006-12-01": cannot parse "-31" as "2"
```

Comment: `format := "2006-01-02"` https://golang.org/pkg/time/

Comment: @peterSO Thanks, that works!

Comment: I promise to you I had read it, but I couldn't understand how it work. Does it means that `2006` always reference to year, `01` reference to month and `02` reference to day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> These are predefined layouts for use in Time.Format and Time.Parse.
>   The reference time used in the layouts is the specific time:
>
> ```
> Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006
> ```
>
> which is Unix time 1136239445. Since MST is GMT-0700, the reference
>   time can be thought of as
>
> ```
> 01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700
> ```
>
> To define your own format, write down what the reference time would
>   look like formatted your way; see the values of constants like ANSIC,
>   StampMicro or Kitchen for examples.

Use `format := "2006-01-02"` for yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: there are impractical limits the following does not work:  t, _ := time.Parse(l"Jan 2, 2006", "Feb 3, 2013 12:34:45")

Answer (score 3):

Per [Go 1.20 release note](https://go.dev/doc/go1.20#minor_library_changes)

> The new time layout constants DateTime, DateOnly, and TimeOnly provide names for three of the most common layout strings used in a survey of public Go source code.

```golang
    DateTime   = "2006-01-02 15:04:05"
    DateOnly   = "2006-01-02"
    TimeOnly   = "15:04:05"
```

The new format [`DateOnly   = "2006-01-02"`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/format.go#L120) of `format.go` will be added in the Go next release (1.20) per proposal [time: add DateTime, DateOnly, TimeOnly format constants](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/52746) and [commit](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/412495)

```golang
time.Parse(time.DateOnly, dateToParse)
```

Comment: Very nice, great addiction to the language. Will make it simple and clear.